# Array loop outputting garbge after the loop ends

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I'm learning to use arrays in C++. It's a really simple program I made to practice the concepts. However, when I start the program, the command prompt outputs garbage after it outputs 1 2 3 4.

When I change the size of the array in the loop to 2, it works. When I change it to zero, it still outputs two values. What's going on? Why does it output 4 values when the array expression is 2? Shouldn't it only output 3 values when it's only 2?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int array[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= array[3]; i++)
    {
        std::cout << array[i] << "\n" << std::flush;
    }


    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change this: `i <= array[3]`, to this: `i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)`, and don't get comfortable with that habit, because that logic goes out the window with a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: @WhozCraig: What does that do?

Comment: for lack of a better term, it computes "the 4" for you. In more depth, it computes the number of elements by integer division, where the size, in bytes, of the entire array is divided by the size, in bytes, of a single array element. The result is the number of elements in the array (in your case, 4). But as I said, it only works for fixed arrays. Dynamic arrays referenced by-pointer are a whole different issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array[3] = 4` so when `i == array[3] == 4` you try to access `array[4]` which isn't defined. You really should use `i < array[3]` or (better yet) `i < 4` since if you have

```
int array[4] = { 0, 2, 5, 100 }
```

then using `array[3]` would be 100 and you would try to loop 100 times.

Comment: Huh. That makes a lot of sense. Is there any way to write a conditional statement using the length of an array?

Comment: @BrandonHoutzer you could do as @WhozCraig said. That determines the length of the array. If you are using C++ though, look into `std::vector` and its `size()` function

Answer (score 2):

You're doing 5 iterations because `array[3] = 4`, then when you print `array[i]`, you're trying to print `array[4]` which is not defined. Try this now :

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    std::cout << array[i] << "\n" << std::flush;
}
```